What verses in the Torah did Samaritans build their hopes for a Messiah upon?
There is a conversation between Jesus and a local Samaritan woman in which she declared:

The woman said, "I know Messiah (called Christ) is coming. When He comes, He will explain everything to us."  (John 4:25)

Since the Samaritan religion only included the Torah in their scriptures---and none of the prophetic books of the Jewish religion---they would not have included any of the Messianic prophecies in their religion found in those later prophetic writings.
So what are the verses in the Torah that "they" would consider Messianic prophecy? Are there any ancient Samaritan writings (commentary) that shows which verses they picked?
We know of limited (obscure) verses Christians might choose, but which would the Samaritans choose that specifically speak of "a coming Messiah"?

Is this question assuming the only source of Samaritan belief is the Samaritan Pentateuch? Samaritans are not a sola scriptura religion

@ Avi Avraham - Can you help us by listing some of the "other scriptures" or Samaritan commentaries?  That would be awesome! Peace.

The Samaritans based their Messianic hopes primarily on the Samaritan Pentateuch, which is similar to the Jewish Torah but contains notable differences. Their expectation of a Messiah is rooted in Deuteronomy 18:15, which states:

"The Lord your God will raise up for you a prophet like me from among you, from your brothers—it is to him you shall listen."

This expected prophet was interpreted by the Samaritans as the Taheb (Samaritan Hebrew: תאהב), meaning "the Restorer." The Taheb would be a prophet like Moses, tasked with restoring true worship on Mount Gerizim, which the Samaritans regarded as the legitimate place of worship.
Additionally, the Samaritans drew upon other passages related to Moses to support their belief that the Taheb would fulfill God’s promises and bring ultimate restoration:

Deuteronomy 34:10 – "And there has not arisen a prophet since in Israel like Moses, whom the Lord knew face to face."

They viewed the coming of the Taheb as a continuation of Moses’ mission.


Exodus 15:17 – "You will bring them in and plant them on your own mountain, the place, O Lord, which you have made for your abode."

This verse reinforced their belief in Mount Gerizim as the central place of worship.



The Samaritans’ exclusive focus on the Torah, rejecting the Jewish Prophets and Writings, shaped a unique Messianic vision centered on Moses and the hope for restoration through the Taheb.

Philip alluded to the passage in Deuteronomy in the following.

Philip found Nathanael and said to him, “We have found him of whom Moses in the Law and also the prophets wrote, Jesus of Nazareth, the son of Joseph.” (John 1:45, ESV2026)

The Samaritans had this passage.

The LORD your God will raise up for you a prophet like me from among you, from your brothers—it is to him you shall listen— 16 just as you desired of the LORD your God at Horeb on the day of the assembly, when you said, ‘Let me not hear again the voice of the LORD my God or see this great fire any more, lest I die.’ 17 And the LORD said to me, ‘They are right in what they have spoken. 18 I will raise up for them a prophet like you from among their brothers. And I will put my words in his mouth, and he shall speak to them all that I command him. 19 And whoever will not listen to my words that he shall speak in my name, I myself will require it of him. 20 But the prophet who presumes to speak a word in my name that I have not commanded him to speak, or who speaks in the name of other gods, that same prophet shall die.’ 21 And if you say in your heart, ‘How may we know the word that the LORD has not spoken?’— 22 when a prophet speaks in the name of the LORD, if the word does not come to pass or come true, that is a word that the LORD has not spoken; the prophet has spoken it presumptuously. You need not be afraid of him. (Deut. 18:15–22ESV2026)

Also see Why did the Samaritan woman use the term, Messiah, in John 4:25?

As the OP's question implies, the Samaritans based their faith on the text of the Samaritan Pentateuch containing only the Torah.  Messianic predictions there are few but still exist.  See my list below - there are possibly others.



Torah Prophecy
Fulfilment




Gen 3:15 - And I will put enmity between you and the woman, and between your seed and her seed.  He will crush your head, and you will strike his heel.
Matt 1:20 - But after he had pondered these things, an angel of the Lord appeared to him in a dream and said, “Joseph, son of David, do not be afraid to embrace Mary as your wife, for the One conceived in her is from the Holy Spirit.  Gal 4:4 - But when the set time had fully come, God sent his Son, born of a woman, born under the law.


Gen 12:3 - I will bless those who bless you and curse those who curse you; and all the families of the earth will be blessed through you.” Gen 18:18 - Abraham will surely become a great and powerful nation, and through him all the nations of the earth will be blessed. Gen 22:18 - And through your offspring all nations of the earth will be blessed, because you have obeyed My voice.”
Acts 3:25 - And you are sons of the prophets and of the covenant God made with your fathers when He said to Abraham, ‘Through your offspring all the families of the earth will be bless . Gal 3:8 - The Scripture foresaw that God would justify the Gentiles by faith, and foretold the gospel to Abraham: “All nations will be blessed through you.”


Gen 49:10 - The scepter will not depart from Judah, nor the staff from between his feet, until Shiloh comes and the allegiance of the nations is his.
Heb 7:14 - For it is clear that our Lord descended from Judah, and in regard to that tribe Moses said nothing about priests.  See also Luke 3:33, Matt 1:2


Num 24:17 - I see him, but not now; I behold him, but not near. A star will come forth from Jacob, and a scepter will arise from Israel. …
Matt 2:2 - “Where is the One who has been born King of the Jews? We saw His star in the east and have come to worship Him.”


Deut 18:15, 18-20 - The LORD your God will raise up for you a prophet like me from among your brothers. You must listen to him. … I will raise up for them a prophet like you from among their brothers. I will put My words in his mouth, and he will tell them everything I command him. And I will hold accountable anyone who does not listen to My words that the prophet speaks in My name. But if any prophet dares to speak a message in My name that I have not commanded him to speak, or to speak in the name of other gods, that prophet must be put to death.”
Acts 3:21-23 - Heaven must take Him in until the time comes for the restoration of all things, which God announced long ago through His holy prophets. For Moses said, ‘The Lord your God will raise up for you a prophet like me from among your brothers. You must listen to Him in everything He tells you.  Everyone who does not listen to Him will be completely cut off from among his people.’




A fine answer: +1.

@ Dottard - These are scriptures that Christians (Jews?) are accustomed to use, to be sure.  But did the Samaritans of the past, and modern Samaritans, use them as well? Are there any Samaritan commentaries and writings to answer this?

@raygrant - there are some references in here >>  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samaritan_Pentateuch

@ Dottard - Excellent! Thanks.
